# Is it possible to update/ write new configuration in hiera_hash with facter or puppet code?

Tags: puppet, puppet-enterprise, hiera, librarian-puppet

I would like to update and maintain my configurations in hiera_hash files. Already, The Hiera_Hash file holds some predefined values. Based on users input I would like to add/ update the new configurations in the hiera_hash file. To do that, I am trying to write it in Factor level and puppet code level. But No idea whether it will work or not.

Guys, Please let me know Whether my scenario is possible / not.

Any help would be much appreciated !!!

Comment: Facter examines the host machine and reports information about it.  It doesn't modify anything.

Comment: If the machine on which your Hiera data store resides is under Puppet management then yes, in principle you could get Puppet to manage the data in response to facts coming in from nodes or otherwise.  But you shouldn't.